# cd ${1:-.} what does that mean

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

```
#====================script 5 -- ls reccurssive avec cd =======
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>/dev/null # redirige stderr pour toute la suite
# au cas ou le script est invoque sans argument $1
# n'existe pas, la commande suivante devient cd .
cd ${1:-.} # problem that i miss understood
for i in * ; do
if [ -d $i ] ; then
echo "$PWD/$i/ <-- repertoire"
$0 $i # le script s'invoque lui-même
else
echo $PWD/$i
fi
done
```

## ===================================================

can someone explain to me this cd ${1:-.} what is mean how to use it if there any article explain this

Comment: Your question already contains the answer in French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${a:-b}` means, as explained in the manual, to use `$a` if it is defined, and otherwise just `b`.

The idea here is that if the script received an argument, `$1` will be defined, and the script will `cd` to that directory. If the script didn't receive an argument, `${1-.}` will expand to the provided *default value*, `.`.

Since `.` means the current directory and `cd .` is a no-op, this basically means, "`cd` to `$1` if available, otherwise simply carry on with the script."